# Image error code 500 on android react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to figure out why I get this error:

[image: Error image]

I used `<Image source:{require('./Path')} />`; this is the code from the official website tutorial.

How can I fix this?
here is the code i used :

```
  `<View style={styles.Container}>
           <Image source={require('/Src/Img/Superman.png')} />
            <Text style={styles.textContainer}> Welcome To Hero App  
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.subTitle}> The Best Place To Ask For 
            Help :) 
            </Text>
        <View style={styles.caseContainer}>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Username" 
                placeholderTextColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
                autoCorrect = {false}                     
                style={styles.input}/>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
                secureTextEntry 
                style={styles.input} />     
        </View> `
```

Comment: It is not able to locate your image , Please check if you have given the correct path

Comment: i used this as a path : {require('./Src/Img/image.png')}

Comment: Please share some of your code, and also check if you are passing right path to require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry guys , i figured out that the path was wrong  , the right answer is this : `<Image source={require('../../Path')} />`

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "=" and not ":" on a component props:

```
<Image source={require('./Path')} />
```

Comment: maybe a problem in your project architecture? Hard to tell without more informations. Maybe the path is simply not good, the path has to start from the file HomePage.js.